# jmp *%esp in Buffer Overflow video

Tags: c, assembly, buffer-overflow

Just started learning about buffer overflow attacks and had a question regarding something in a video I saw https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcMCiFwHnjE/. In the video, why does the person write `jmpesp()` function (~1:38)? The function is never called anywhere in main so how does it appear on the `objdump` (~3:15)? Also what is the significance of the `jmp *%esp`?

Answer (score 0):

`jmp *%esp` means to jump (set the instruction pointer) to the location pointed to by the `%esp` register, which is pointer to the top of the stack. So the most recent (usually data) stuff pushed on the stack will be executed as code.

Comment: How is that code executed though? The function `jmpesp()` is never called in the main. I thought for a function to be used it had to be called in the main or at least indirectly from main?

Comment: AFAIK, `jmp *%esp` is an indirect jump (see the *). Thus, the jump goes to the address specified at the memory location pointed to by %esp.